# Error in data != 0x002A when selecting a picture with Phonegap Camera plugin - Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I am porting a phonegap app to windows-phone-8.
Using the phonegap camera plugin I am using this function:

```
function chooseFile() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoCaptureSuccess, onPhotoCaptureFail,
            {
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            }
    ); 
}
```

it opens up my gallery but when I select my picture, it give me this message (in the output console):

```
Error in data != 0x002A
```

(which is a line code contained in the file **ImageExifHelper.cs**)

and the image selected is not displayed.

What is going on?
How to make it work?

Comment: I got the same problem, did you sort it?

Comment: I solved it by upgrading from 3.6 to cordova 3.7

Comment: I have upgraded to 3.7.1 (cordova 4.3.0) and i still get it.  Running camera plugin 0.3.6... What version of plugin you using?

Comment: org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.5 "Camera"

Comment: here the others: org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.5 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.11 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.15 "Media"
org.apache.cordova.media-capture 0.3.5 "Capture"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 0.3.5 "Splashscreen"